# Select Values from Same Column Based on Value in Different Row (Like INDEX/MATCH?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
ID          Status  Datestamp

241112069   Stop    6/15/2016 16:46
241112069   Start   6/15/2016 16:28
241108880   Stop    6/15/2016 15:42
241105741   Finish  6/15/2016 17:58
241105741   Start   6/15/2016 15:24
241105741   Stop    6/15/2016 15:24
241105111   Stop    6/15/2016 15:31
241105111   Stop    6/15/2016 15:31
241105111   Start   6/15/2016 15:31
241105110   Stop    6/15/2016 15:31
241105110   Start   6/15/2016 15:31
241105110   Stop    6/15/2016 15:31
241105109   Stop    6/15/2016 15:31
241105109   Stop    6/15/2016 15:31
241103498   Stop    6/15/2016 15:12
241103498   Start   6/15/2016 15:12
241102948   Stop    6/15/2016 15:10
241102380   Stop    6/15/2016 15:07
241101836   Stop    6/15/2016 15:03
241101836   Start   6/15/2016 15:03
241101835   Stop    6/15/2016 15:03
241101835   Start   6/15/2016 15:03
241101537   Finish  6/15/2016 17:55
241101537   Stop    6/15/2016 15:02
241101537   Start   6/15/2016 15:02
241097936   Stop    6/15/2016 14:54
241097936   Finish  6/15/2016 15:16
241097936   Start   6/15/2016 14:44
```

I'm attempting to write a select query that will basically return the distinct ID and then three new columns that contain the date stamp for each status (start, stop, finish). Racking my head around case, subqueries, etc. but not getting the result I want. I would use INDEX/MATCH in Excel but this database is gigantic.

Caveat:

1. There can be multiple status entries for the same status/order or blank values. For the multiple entries, I'd want just the first one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be some inner join

```
select a.id, min(a.datestamp) as start, min(b.datestamp) as stop, min( c.datestamp ) as finish
from my_table as a
inner join my_table as b on a.id = b.id and b.status = 'stop'
inner join my_table as c on a.id = c.id and c.status = 'Finish'
where  a.status = 'Start';
group by a.id
```

Comment: `and a.status = 'Start';` needs to be `where a.status = 'Start';`

Comment: @BrianRudolph  right  .. thanks .. i have update the answer

Comment: Wow, guess I overthought this. Didn't think of doing a self join!

Comment: well .. is thid what you are looking for ?